# Include Alertify module js file in module_catalog/view/frontend/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js in magento2

Tags: magento2, catalog

We have include the alertify js module in magento2 its loading perfectly with frontname, we have to inlude those aletify in `module_catalog/view/frontend/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js`

How to include this?

Comment: define in require js of your catalog module and use those defined variable in catalog-add-to-cart.js @shivashankar m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the alertify files at web js and css files in

```
app/design/frontend/vendor/magento/Magento_Catalog
```

call the css and js files under:

```
app/design/frontend/vendor/magento/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml
```

Then call inlude alertify under

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js
```

find the code:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/translate',
    "alertify",
    'jquery/ui'
], function($, $t, alertify) {
    "use strict";
```

Now you can use alertify for popup like below:

```
if (res.multicart && res.multicart.error) {
    alertify.alert(res.multicart.error);
}
```